# Probability biased and unbiased coin

Tags: probability

Suppose that we have $2$ coins, a fair one (probability of $H$ or $T$ = $0.5$), lets call this $C_1$ and a biased one (probability of $H = 0.6,$ $T = 0.4$), lets call this $C_2$.

Then if we pick one of the coins at random and look at the result of a coin toss for which we get a $H$ result, why can we say that the probability of the coin being $C_1 = 0.4$ and being $C_2 = 0.6$ respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Bayes' Theorem

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{Coin 1 | } H)
&=\frac{P(\text{Coin 1} \cap H)}{P(H)}\\\\
&=\frac{0.5\cdot0.5}{(0.5\cdot0.5)+(0.5\cdot0.6)}\\\\
&\approx0.455
\end{align*}$$

and so $$P(\text{Coin 2 | } H)=1-P(\text{Coin 1 | } H)\approx0.545$$

It does not appear that the probability that it was coin one given that you obtained heads it $0.4$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  My question was based on a question posted on stack exchange: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/76647/what-is-meant-by-the-term-prior-in-machine-learning

Comment: I could not understand where the values were coming from

Comment: As someone in the comments pointed out, there were errors in the accepted answer.